# Can't login to windows 10

Tags: windows-10

After windows 10 has perform an update I can't login to windows.
(The computer is not mine, it is my friend computer)

I have used a PIN code to login to windows, and after the update it no longer accept the PIN code.

I don't know the email address nor the password.

I already tried to restart with command prompt, to enabled administrator.

Nothing worked, i always asked to provide a password that i don't have.

I don't want to erase and reinstall again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to provide the password.

Comment: I am sorry for missing the duplicate question it resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

After an update and Windows has restarted, you will be asked for your password and not your PIN. Change the option of entering a password to enter a PIN instead by clicking on *Sign-in options* just below the password box. You can then enter your PIN and will be able to login.

Here's an image of the sign-in option you're required to select:

[image: Windows login using a PIN]

Comment: How do they chnage it?  Be specific.

Comment: There is an option of changing the mode (password/pin) below the textbox where you enter your pin/password

Comment: Click on sign in options below that box and click the option with 10 dots

Comment: @Ramhound you can refer to the link attached in the edited comment.

Comment: I don't have to; I already knew how to do it; the author didn't

Comment: You needed an explanation, so I gave.

Comment: I asked for clarification, because your answer was incomplete, huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote in the question Windows doesn't accept the PIN and I forgot the password

Comment: Did you enter your pin in the box where pin is asked or in the box where password is asked? I told you the change in mode that Windows does after every update. You'll have to change the mode to pin-entry everytime you do any cumulative Windows update.